# Is there a way to programmatically mark a shipping email as sent?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there a way to programmatically mark a shipping email as sent? After combing through Google for some help, I have come up empty handed.

I have set up an observer to send out an email as soon as a tracking number is added to a shipment, but I need to be able to some how show in the admin that the email has been sent instead of displaying "the shipment email is not sent."

**UPDATE**

Here is the code that I have. I can get the email to send just fine, but I cannot get the email_sent flag to be set

```
class WR_TrackingEmail_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendTrackEmail($observer)
    {
        $track = $observer->getEvent()->getTrack();
        $shipment = $track->getShipment(true);
        $shipment->sendEmail();
        $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

After trying the following code, I run into a new issue. The item is marked as shipped but for some reason I get a million copies of the shipping email. I am assuming that a loop is happening somewhere. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
public function sendTrackEmail($observer)
{
    $track = $observer->getEvent()->getTrack();
    $shipment = $track->getShipment(true);
    $shipment->sendEmail();
    $shipment->setEmailSent(true);

    $saveTransaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                   ->addObject($shipment)
                   ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                   ->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is the way to set all the Shipment statuses, along with all the notification emails:-

```
$_eachOrderTrackingNum = 'ANY_SPECIFIC_TRACKING_NUMBER';
$arrTracking = array(
    'carrier_code' => 'ups',
    'title' => 'United Parcel Service',
    'number' => $_eachOrderTrackingNum,
);

$track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($arrTracking);
$shipment->addTrack($track);
$emailSentStatus = $shipment->getData('email_sent');

$customerEmail = $order->getData('customer_email');
if (!is_null($customerEmail) && !$emailSentStatus) {
    $shipment->sendEmail($customerEmail, '');
    $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
}

$saveTransaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                   ->addObject($shipment)
                   ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                   ->save();
```

Here "`$shipment`" is an object of "`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment`", after the order has been converted to this Shipment object. Also the "`$order`" is the specific Order object.

Hope it helps.

---

**UPDATE**

After seeing your update, it seems that you need to use the following code for your method "`sendTrackEmail()`":-

```
public function sendTrackEmail($observer)
{
    $track = $observer->getEvent()->getTrack();
    $shipment = $track->getShipment(true);
    $shipment->sendEmail();
    $shipment->setEmailSent(true);

    $saveTransaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                   ->addObject($shipment)
                   ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                   ->save();
}
```

Comment: That only gets me stuck in a loop of some kind that fires off about a million emails....